# Undefined Variable php login system / unity

Tags: php, mysql

> I 'm getting this error: Warning: Undefined variable $loginUser in C:\xampp\htdocs\BNP\Login.php on line 21
> Username does not exist. I tried other fixed but it's returning the same error message. Can anyone please help?

```
<?php

//variables for connecting to DB
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "unityaccess";

//variables submitted by user
if(isset($_POST['loginUser'])){ $loginUser = $_POST['loginUser']; }
if(isset($_POST['loginPass'])){ $loginPass = $_POST['loginPass']; }

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '" . $loginUser . "'";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if($row["password"] == $loginPass){
    echo "Login Success, welcome.";
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Credentials";
}
  }
} else {
  echo "Username does not exists";
}

$conn = null;



?>
```

> thankss

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. How is your question related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Your $loginUser is not defined and also check your form name attribute have 'loginUser' and also use this updated code it will work i defined $loginUser in this.

[image]

```
<?php
    
    //variables for connecting to DB
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "unityaccess";

   $loginUser = $_POST['loginUser'];
    
    //variables submitted by user
    if(isset($_POST['loginUser'])){ $loginUser = $_POST['loginUser']; }
    if(isset($_POST['loginPass'])){ $loginPass = $_POST['loginPass']; }
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '" . $loginUser . "'";
    
    
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["password"] == $loginPass){
        echo "Login Success, welcome.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Credentials";
    }
      }
    } else {
      echo "Username does not exists";
    }
    
    $conn = null;
    
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: nope, if page accessed directly {without form submitting form), it will give error in future as well, best practice will be check if data exist else create or show don't run further part

Comment: yes but as per standard method we can not submit form with empty input element for that we have to apply client side validation like jQuery validation and also we have to apply validation on server side.

Comment: no that is not always necessary, here person is using pure php not an framework, you can send GET POST request without form as well.

Comment: yes we can send GET POST request without form but without client and server side validation it's not secure

Comment: and here person was not received value in $loginUser that's why it's showing warning

Comment: kids now days : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244421/discussion-between-dotsquares-and-shubham-dange).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set $loginuser in else part,on line no. 10 > where you are checking if isset($_POST['loginUser']), set some thing in else part so you will not get error.

```
<?php

//variables for connecting to DB
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "unityaccess";

//variables submitted by user
if(isset($_POST['loginUser'])){ $loginUser = $_POST['loginUser']; } else { $loginUser =  "am RANDOM DATA that will give make sql query false";}
if(isset($_POST['loginPass'])){ $loginPass = $_POST['loginPass']; } else { $loginPass =  "am RANDOM DATA that will give make sql query false";}

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '" . $loginUser . "'";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
if($row["password"] == $loginPass){
    echo "Login Success, welcome.";
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Credentials";
}
  }
} else {
  echo "Username does not exists";
}

$conn = null;



?>
```